# calculate limit of two variable function at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{\ln(x+e^y)-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ find $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$

I've already checked that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0$ but I'm using taylor series and I'm curious whether there is some tricky way to calculate it without taylor.

Comment: We can polar and use L'Hospital rule but it seems to need more steps.

Answer (score 0):

Or we have$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(x+e^y)-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+\frac x{e^y})+\ln e^y-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+\frac x{e^y})-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+\frac x{e^y})^{\frac {e^y}x}-e^y}{\frac {e^y}x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-e^y}{\frac {e^y}x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x(\frac 1{e^y}-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

note that$$|\frac{x(\frac 1{e^y}-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0|\leq |\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta=\epsilon$$
then we have $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0$